# displaying ajax results in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

From my code, it displays the hall input type tag inside the textbox.
I want only the value to be displayed.

---

ajax function:

```
function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"php_action/newfetchorder.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {

     $('#firstName').val(data);

   }

  });
 }
```

---

html:

```
<input  type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"  />
```

---

php:

```
if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM product 
    WHERE Barcode LIKE '%".$search."%'
     ";

     $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
     $output1 .= '<input type="text" name="item_name" value="'.$row["product_name"].'">';
     // $output2 .= '<input type="text" name="item_price" value="'.$row["Retail_price"].'">';
  }
  echo $output1;

}
else {
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}
}
```

---

output:

[image]

---

expected output:

[image]

Comment: Could you put a php code?

Comment: which result return from ajax in data see using `alert` or `console.log`

Comment: Is `newfetchorder.php` returning JSON? show us the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write `$output1 .=$row["product_name"]` instead of `$output1 .= '<input type="text" name="item_name" value="'.$row["product_name"].'">';`

simple store value to `$output1 variable and echo it` no need to assign `textbox here`

Answer (score -1):

change this code line

---

```
 $output1 .= '<input type="text" name="item_name" value="'.$row["product_name"].'">';
```

to

```
$output1 = $row["$product_name"];
```